# как получить историю транзакций tron кошелька на python

Tags: python, tron

искал как это сделать в tronpy но не смог разобраться

Answer (score 0):

нашёл способ с помощью requests

```
import requests

def get_transactions(wallet_address):
url = f"https://apilist.tronscan.org/api/transaction?sort=-timestamp&count=true&limit=50&start=0&address={wallet_address}"
response = requests.get(url)
transactions = response.json()
return transactions

wallet_address = "Кошелёк trx для поиска"
transactions = get_transactions(wallet_address)
```

ответ будет в виде dict